# How to add formula to multiple cells in that row without dragging?

Tags: excel, range, formula

Very Simple Question:

How do I make:

=A1

Apply from B1:B640250

with out Dragging them manually?

thanks

Comment: VBA: `Range("B1:B640250").Formula = "=A1"`. Or use a table. Or Ctrl+D to fill down.

Comment: When I add that, the actual text appears in the box, it doesn't formulate. "Range("B1:B640250").Formula = "=A1"

Comment: Also the Ctrl+D thing didnt work.

Comment: if there is data in column A all you need to do is double click the fill handle on B1 and it will automatically fill the column

Comment: @steve, that is vba not a formula.  would create a Subroutine in the VBE and run it.

Comment: Or just enter it into the Immediate Window in the VBE and hit Enter.

Comment: If one has an Office 365 subscription and the Dynamic array formulas, then in B1 put `=A1:A640250` and Excel will spill the results.

Comment: "that is vba not a formula. would create a Subroutine in the VBE and run it." -I have no idea what that means :S

Comment: @ScottCraner This worked perfectly. Thank you. Also thanks everybody. "If one has an Office 365 subscription and the Dynamic array formulas, then in B1 put =A1:A640250 and Excel will spill the results."

Answer (score 1):

1. Type formula into `B1` cell.
2. Copy formula.
3. Type address `B640250` into `Name box` and press `Enter`.
4. Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Arrow Up`
5. Press `Enter`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you still have to use your mouse but you can highlight the whole area you want it to fill and then there should be fill without formatting option available to you. Sorry if I didnt explain this well enough.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/01/20/copy-formula-excel/